# Ionic1 - Cordova-ios - Provisioning Profile Push Notification Error

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, cordova-ios, ionic-v1

I have an issue building my ionic app on iOS.
If I run the release build command, the archive succeeds but the export fails with this error:

> error: exportArchive: “TeaZe.app” requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.
>
> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ““TeaZe.app” requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.” UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=“TeaZe.app” requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the “provisioningProfiles” dictionary in your Export Options property list.}

** EXPORT FAILED **

The provisioning profile definitely has the push notification service:
[image: Provisioning Profile]

The capability is enabled in xcode:
[image: XCode Push Notifications]

I can still build and archive the app in xcode with no errors but I find push notifications are not working anymore!

My build environment:

```
Ionic CLI 3.20.0
ionic1 1.3.3
ios 4.5.3
XCode 9.3
```

It looks like some file is being misconfigured for cordova but I have not idea what to do.
I deleted all my certs/profiles and re-created, updated xcode and cordova-ios to the latest.
Also tried downgrading xcode but was not compatible with my iphone so it was not worth it.

Anyone came across this?

Answer (score 0):

I’m still getting this error on CLI but I got notifications working again. I recreated my cert, auth key and provisioning profile, deleted and setup everything again in FCM. I just do a ionic cordova prepare and build the app in xcode then.

I’m pretty sure the problem is current version of cordova-ios is not updating something!